# Do I need to use another property other than "text-align" to center my DIV within a DIV?

Tags: html, css, center, text-alignment, text-align

I want to center a DIV within a parent DIV.  I have tried using the recommende dsolution on SO -- [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div), but its not centering it.  The basic layout is this

```css
#revealScoreMobile {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.stats {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="revealScoreMobile">
  ...
  <div class="stats" style="">
    <div class="score">5.0</div>
    (<span class="votesCast">1</span> votes cast)
  </div>
</div>
```

and yet as you can see from the Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/5Lgu0uw3/2/,  the child DIV is not centering within the parent, despite the fact I have

```
text-align:center;
```

in there.  What gives?  What else do I need to do to center that DIV within its parent?

Comment: Text-align: center; does only center **TEXT** so yes, you need more then it to center align it.

Comment: yes, you need to use another property other than `text-align`. Also, this site has a "search" function: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+div ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Comment: @giorgiga, I edited my question to add more detail.  I tried the "margin: 0 auto;" as recommended by that solution and it didn't work -- https://jsfiddle.net/5Lgu0uw3/2/ .  I edited my quesiton to elaborate more.

Comment: @Persijn, What is this mystical extra property of which you speak?

Comment: Note that is not a minimal example. In the fiddle, you have set `.stats` to `display: table-cell` which alters the dynamic.

Comment: append `#revealScoreMobile { margin: 0 auto; width: 250px }` to your css. Note this is exactly what is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div

Comment: @giorgiga, Oh I thought they wnted to apply that property on the inner DIV, whereas "#revealScoreMobile" is my outer DIV.  Still I tried that property on the outer DIV and it did not center the inner DIV -- https://jsfiddle.net/5Lgu0uw3/4/ .

Comment: That's ok @Natalia - sorry if I've been rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you want, but if you want the inner DIV NOT have the full width, but only as much as its text contents require, make it an `inline-block` and erase the `width`setting (or give it a `width`setting less than 100%). `inline-block`s  *are*  affected by `text-align: center`

(note that I erased some superfluous settings, but put the `...` content into its own DIV, since it otherwise would be on one line with the subsequent inline-block.

```css
#revealScoreMobile {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.stats {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="revealScoreMobile">
 <div> ... </div>
  <div class="stats" style="">
    <div class="score">5.0</div>
    (<span class="votesCast">1</span> votes cast)
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested in the comments, `text-align: center;` only applies to text content, not the inner `div`.

Your CSS applies `width: 100%;` to `.stats` which is forcing it to take up the full width of it's parent container `#revealScoreMobile`, which is also `width: 100%;`. Secondly it needs `display: inline-block;` to override the previous `display: table-cell;` as present in your jsfiddle example.

Replace in your CSS:

```
.stats {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```